# Pylint doesn't show anything on Eclipse

Tags: python-3.x, pydev, pylint

I have installed the latest pylint and it works fine from Windows command line. I have added Pydev-PYTHONPATH with source directory that I want to lint. Also from PyDev->PyLint I've selected 'Use pylint' and updated 'Location of pylint (lint.py):' with the correct lint.py. I don't see any lint output on either the Console or Problem view. My Eclipse is version 3.7.2.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is "latest" 0.26.0? Which version of pydev are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some changes in the formatting of the messages in pylint 0.26 (http://www.logilab.org/ticket/104572) which likely need a pydev update to be properly handled. You should contact the Pydev author and request support for this.

If you can easily configure the command line for pylint in pydev, try adding `--include_ids=y` and see if this helps.

Comment: PyDev version 2.7.1.201200913. I've tried your suggestion but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: then this is really a pydev issue, and you should follow the procedure described at http://pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIReportaBUG%3F to report a bug. A quick search in the list did not return anything like your issue.

Comment: I've added one: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3576831&group_id=85796&atid=577329